# How do i print all the odd numbers?

Tags: c

I want to print all the odd numbers from 14 to 156 using an infinite loop, break and continue. But, when i run it does not display anything!!

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int y = 14;
    while(x) {
        if(y % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else if(y % 3 == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", y);
        }
        if(y == 156) {
            break;
        }
        y++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `while(x)` to `while(1)`. Most likely `x` gets initialized to zero.

Comment: Why are you using `y%3` if you're just looking for odd numbers?

Comment: @MadPhysicist don't believe it: using an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour. `x` is not initialised at all.

Comment: even if i initialize x=1 at the beginning I'm getting no output!

Comment: @WeatherVane. Have you tried running this? Undefined does not mean "magic", it just means that the compiler is free to do whatever it wants. In most cases, it will leave whatever trash was in memory at the time. As often as not, that is zero.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you contradict yourself. Earlier your "most likely" was initialised to 0. Now you say "in most cases" is not initialised at all. And it isn't. It is not a matter of the compiler being "free to do what it wants". The value is uninitialised, end of.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Fair enough. The earlier statement should have been "Most likely `x` retains the value zero because it is whatever garbage was in memory when your function was called."

Comment: @WeatherVane. Let me know if you like the first paragraph of my answer. I tried to address all the issues you brought up.

Comment: @WeatherVane. I will interpret that as a compliment :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist the first paragraph is good, but I wish your solution had improved the infinite `while` loop the OP was using, instead of changing to an incomplete `for` loop and only mentioning the `while(1)` loop as an afterthought, without full implementation.

Comment: the thing is that I am required to use a while loop!

Comment: @MahmoudHamra: You didn't mention that requirement in the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane. I addressed the specific issue with `continue` and not incrementing the number. Full implementation is now in there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it uses an operation with unpredictable results. Specifically, declaring `int x;` without initializing it, and then using it as your termination condition in `while(x)` is the problem. On many platforms and compilers, this will retain whatever value was already in the memory occupied by `x`. In that case, you may see no print statements because `x` starts with the value zero and the loop never runs.

You should make your loop into an infinite loop:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    for(x = 14; ; x++) {
        if(x % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if(x >= 156) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[[IDEOne link]](https://ideone.com/WKmQb5)

This will print the values excluding `156` itself. To include `156`, put the `break` condition after the `printf` call:

```
printf("%d\n", x);
if(x >= 156) {
    break;
}
```

Alternatively you can change `>=` to just `>`.

You do not need `else` if you have `break` or `continue`.

If you have to use a while loop, the situation is a tad more complex because you have to increment before you `continue` to avoid an infinite loop:

```
int main() {
    int x = 14;
    while(1) {
        if(x % 2 == 0) {
            x++;
            continue;
        }
        if(x >= 156) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", x++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/QgIGxJ)

You can avoid the extra increment if you can forgo the `continue`:

```
int main() {
    int x = 14;
    while(1) {
        if(x % 2) {
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
        if(x++ == 156) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/U8tKXt)

I have also removed your check for `x % 3 == 0` since it is not clear what the purpose of that is within the constraints of your problem.

Comment: have *you* tried running your own code? I mean, the first `while(1)` example, which is not "full" anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane. No I did not (when you first asked), but I did now, and updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With an infinite loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int y=14;
while(1){
    if(y & 1){
        printf("%d\n",y);
    }

    if(y>=156){
        break;
    }

    y++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Preferred method, with for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int start=14;
start |= 1; //This will increment by one if your start value is even
for (start; start<=146; start+=2) {
    printf("%d\n", start);  
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0b1` is a GNU only extension as far as I am aware. `0x1`, or just testing with `% 2` would be more portable. In fact your whole ternary expression can be replaced by `start += (start & 1)` since `start & 1` is guaranteed to be 0 or 1 exactly.

Comment: I edited with those suggestions, thanks! `start |= 1;` is a cool way of doing that, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop with a break is not the right way to do this. Use a "for" loop and your code will be much clearer. Start it at 15 and increment by 2 until 156.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your logic.

```
1. Variable `x` is of no use. You can use variable `y` to terminate the loop.
2. No need to check if the number is a multiple of 3.
3. No need to check for even numbers is either.
```

I have modified the code and it is giving correct results but I'll urge you to read the above points and try to get the code right.

```
int main()
{
    int y = 14;
    while(y) {
        if (y==156)
            break;
        if(y % 2 != 0) {
            printf("%d ",y);
        }
        y++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A better and faster way would be to start with 15 and increment variable `y`'s value by 2 till its <=156.

```
int main()
    {
        int y = 15;
        while(y) {
            if (y==157)
                break;
            printf("%d ",y);
            y+=2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior because the variable `x` is uninitialized and used as the condition in the `while` statement.  You could fix this with `while (1)` but there would indeed be an infinite loop in your program because the test for evenness occurs before the test for termination on `156`.

The problem is solved simply with a standard `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int y = 14; y < 156; y++) {
        if (y % 2 != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which can be simplified as this, only enumerating odd numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int y = 15; y < 156; y += 2) {
        printf("%d\n", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you are required to use `break`, `continue` and a *infinite loop*, you can indeed use the classic forever C loop, a `for` loop without a termination condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int y = 14;; y++) {
        if (y == 156)
            break;
        if (y % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        printf("%d\n", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Prints even or add numbers between to and from.
   Works for negative numbers.
   Works up and down.
 */
int print_even_or_odd(long long from, long long to, int even)
{
  if (((INT32_MAX < from) || (INT32_MIN > from)) ||
      ((INT32_MAX < to) || (INT32_MIN > to)))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
  }

  printf("from=%d to %d\n", (int) from, (int) to);

  int sign = (to < from) ?-1 :1;

  /* Adjust "from" to next even/odd number. */
  if ((!even && !(from & 1)) || (even && (from & 1)))
  {
     from += sign;
  }

  /* Adjust "to" to the previous even/odd number. */
  if ((!even && !(to & 1)) || (even && (to & 1)))
  {
    to -= sign;
  }

  {
    size_t steps = (size_t) (sign * ((to - from) / 2)) + 1;

    if (0 == steps)
    {
      printf("Nothing to do.\n");
      return 0;
    }

    while (1)
    {
      if (0 >= steps)
      {
        break;
      }

      --steps;

      printf("%d\n", (int) (to - sign * 2 * (int) steps));

      continue; /* as having continue is a requirement ... ;-) */
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  print_even(14, 156, 0);
  print_even(156, 14, 0);
  print_even(-14, -156, 0);
  print_even(-156, -14, 0);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie: Ups ... well "even", "odd" who cares .. ;-) will amend this. And yes indeed. I missed the requirement for an infinite loop, although I feel a loop with a break could not really be considered infinite any more, right?

Comment: @chqrlie Any way, fixed.

Comment: Playing Mr picky: `(to - from)` has a potential arithmetic overflow.

Comment: not a proper fix: if `INT_MAX == LONG_MAX` (as is the case on Windows), input validation will succeed but the potential arithmetic overflow remains.  It is actually even present here: `from += sign;` for `even == 1` and `to == from == INT_MAX` and the same for `to -= sign;` if `even == 0` and `to == from == INT_MIN`.

Comment: Ok, fair enough @chqrlie ... -  so I made `to` and `from` `long long` then. This is backed by the Standard to always be wider then `int`.

Comment: no it is not. `int` and `long long` may both be 64 bits.  The Standard only guarantees that `long long` has at least 63 value bits.

Comment: @chqrlie Haa, yes, you are right again. So let's nail this differently then. Editing ...